# How to set TexTbox to resize automatically depending on TextBlock. WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, textbox, textblock

I want to make something like a TextBlock and has a TextBox infront of it.
However, my app is localizable so the TextBlock can sometimes contains long text and sometimes short so I want the textbox to resize itself automatically depending on TextBlock's width.

I tried to do it with a stackpanel but failed xD:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="auto" Height="auto">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Text="{Resx Key=TextBlock_ProjectName}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="ProjectNameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,10,0,0" MinWidth="770" MaxWidth="770"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Whenever the textblock gets a bigger text, The textbox actually MOVES to the right and not resized..

I just need to be pushed to the right way, any help is appreciated.

E: My current code using Grids:

```
<Grid>
    <Menu x:Name="menu" Height="34" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="885" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <MenuItem Header="{Resx Key=StartupForm_MenuItem_OpenGlobalSettings}" Height="34"/>
    </Menu>
    <TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl" Height="297" Margin="0,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="887" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TabItem Header="{Resx Key=StartupForm_TabItem_NewProject}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="770" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,0,0" Text="{Resx Key=StartupForm_TextBlock_ProjectName}"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ProjectNameTextBox" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,47,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Resx Key=StartupForm_TextBlock_SAMPVersion}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ListBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="111" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="765" Margin="105,47,0,0" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" />

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="textBlock2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,191,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Project Location: " VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="checkBox" Content="Create from pre-existing files." Margin="105,162,-95,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                <controls1:PathTextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="textBox1" Height="28" Margin="105,0,11,39" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="765" RenderTransformOrigin="0.075,-0.154" IsDirectory="True" TheDesc="Please choose a directory for the project."/>
                
                <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Create Project" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="861" Style="{DynamicResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Load Project"/>
        <TabItem Header="Recent"/>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a Grid with 2 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like what [Karmacon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1470467/karmacon) suggested in the comments, it's easiest to do it with Grid. (Edit: perhaps not easiest, but it's probably the one that gives the exact result you need)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="770" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,0,0" Text="{Resx Key=TextBlock_ProjectName}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ProjectNameTextBox" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Of course, I did some changes based on some assumptions, which I believe is pretty obvious.

Comment: it just doesn't work .. Please check my code if there is something wrong.
Added it to main post.
its like that the second column is like to the very right.

Comment: @Ahmad45123 lol... I didn't think much about how the margin would affect the layout, I assumed it's your own design requirement :D

Comment: No, your margins aren't wrong, those are correct.. Margins where wrong on the other controls and also I had the Width set to a fixed number which also didn't work.. Had to make sure to size it as using the margins.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DockPanel instead.

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Text="{Resx Key=TextBlock_ProjectName}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="ProjectNameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,10,0,0" MinWidth="770" MaxWidth="770"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: You're missing the `DockPanel.Dock` to dock the TextBlock to the left side. Also depending on the parent panel, you may need to set a Width on the DockPanel itself :)

Comment: This also worked, thanks.. But I prefer using the Grid.